# Cant use second monitor

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, vga, external-display, manjaro

I have a really old monitor (BENQ FP731) and I've been trying to get it to work on my Manjaro laptop but not much success so far. I'm using an HDMI to VGA adapter. My laptop appears to be detecting the monitor but I only get a black screen. Any ideas?

Note: The monitor works just fine on my windows boot

Edit: Running xrandr auto gives me a `Configure crtc 3 failed` error.

Comment: You could be feeding an unsupported video mode. Have you tried a different resolution? 640x480 should be fairly safe and well supported (if you can go that low with whatever source you're using, otherwise try 800x600). It looks like a 1280x720 panel, so aim for that and no higher.

Comment: Tried those none worked, the monitor keeps giving me "no signal detected" every time I switch it off and back on again, otherwise it's just black.

Comment: I am dual booting my laptop and on the windows boot the monitor works just fine, that's the weird thing about this whole situation.